# Batch change of object name

Tags: python, scripting

I have several models and I want to change the object name to the object data property name in batches using a script.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can access an object's data via `<objectDataPath>.data`, and their names via `.name`. To make this user-controlled, let's limit it to a selection of objects by getting a list of the selected objects and loop through it:

```py
import bpy

sel = bpy.context.selected_objects

for i in sel:
    print (f'Renaming {i.name} to {i.data.name}')
    i.name = i.data.name
```